# Creation of table columns using artisan migration

Tags: laravel-4, migrate

Using `artisan migrate` command, i am trying to create the table. `users` table is created but not the columns. What could I check ?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;


class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the table is created, because your file is ok! Could you check by deleting it and migrate again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon running the above migration file, the table and its columns are successfully created in the database. If you see that the `users` table is created but not the columns in it, then you might not be looking properly.

I am writing the following answer on my assumption that you're very new to web development also and might not be acquainted with the tools yet.

I assume you're using `phpMyAdmin` to view your database. If you go to your database and then the users table, you'll be in the `Browse` tab. Of course, it will be empty because there are no data inserted in the `users` table, but if you click the `Structure` tab, then you can view the schema of your `users` table and see that the columns are created.

Comment: Thanks.. I forgot to check the columns in structure tab.